# How to aggregate a column if only specific string appears in group

Tags: sql

I am extracting two types of products (pizza and sides) from grouped transactions but would like to create individual aggregates for specific transactions with conditions such as if a transaction contains:

1. Only pizza and no sides
2. Sides and no pizzas
3. Both pizza and sides

For orders that contain only pizza, I'd like to sum the number of items and then divide by 2.

If an order contains only sides then I'd like to sum the number of items then divide by 3.

If an transaction contains pizza and sides, then I'd like to sum the number of items and divide by 3 if there are less than 2 pizzas in a transaction and divide by 2 if there are more than 2 pizzas in a transaction.

The following is a snip of the code I am using to do the initial sums and calculations but I can't figure out how to create the conditions I need without it aggregating the wrong items. I tried doing one of the conditions to only find orders with pizzas and no sides but the case when statement still aggregates all orders with pizza even if they have a side with the transaction and outputs a null for rows with 'sides'.

```
with q as (
select uniqueorderid, types, counts
,SUM(tcounts)  OVER (PARTITION BY UniqueOrderId) as counts
from k
order by uniqueorderid
)

select uniqueorderid, types, tcounts, ocounts
, case
when types = 'pizza' and 'sides' not in ( SELECT types FROM k ) THEN ceiling(tcounts/2)
end as counts

from q
order by uniqueorderid
```

Here is a small sample of the data:

```
uniqueorderid,types,tcounts
7e,pizza,2.0
f4,sides,0.5
8c,sides,1.5
8c,pizza,3.0
bb,pizza,1.0
04,pizza,2.0
```

Possible solution:

```
SELECT uniqueorderid

       ,CASE 
         WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN types = 'pizza' THEN tcounts ELSE 0 END) = 0 
              AND SUM(CASE WHEN types = 'sides' THEN tcounts ELSE 0 END) > 0 
              THEN ceiling(SUM(tcounts) / 3.0)
         WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN types = 'sides' THEN tcounts ELSE 0 END) = 0 
              AND SUM(CASE WHEN types = 'pizza' THEN tcounts ELSE 0 END) > 0 
              THEN ceiling(SUM(tcounts) / 2.0)
         WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN types = 'pizza' THEN tcounts ELSE 0 END) > 0 
              AND SUM(CASE WHEN types = 'sides' THEN tcounts ELSE 0 END) > 0 
              THEN 
              CASE 
                WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN types = 'pizza' THEN tcounts ELSE 0 END) > 2 
                     THEN ceiling(SUM(tcounts) / 2.0 )
                ELSE ceiling(SUM(tcounts) / 3.0 )
              END
         ELSE NULL
       END AS pcounts
FROM k
GROUP BY uniqueorderid
order by uniqueorderid
```

Comment: What DBMS is used? Is it possible for 1 order to contain multiples of the same type?

Comment: it is a relational database. it is possible for 1 order to contain multiples of the same type.

Comment: The question is _which_ relational database. Different DBMSes can require different syntax.

Comment: What is your expected output? Does your "possible solution" output what you want?

Comment: *...if there are less than 2 pizzas in a transaction...* by your code I assume that this case includes the number 2 also and not just <2. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

The conditions for your requirement can be simplified to:

> I'd like to sum the number of items and divide by:
>
> - 3, if the number of pizzas is <= 2 in a transaction (this covers 0 or 1 or 2 pizzas regardless the number of sides)
> - 2, in any other case

For this you need aggregation and a `CASE` expression for the 2 cases:

```
SELECT uniqueorderid,
       CEILING(
         SUM(tcounts) /
         CASE 
           WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN types = 'pizza' THEN 1 END) <= 2 THEN 3
           ELSE 2
         END
       ) AS pcounts
FROM k
WHERE types IN ('pizza', 'sides') -- remove this line if these 2 are the only options for types
GROUP BY uniqueorderid
ORDER BY uniqueorderid;
```